# Adding a class to a backbone form element?

Tags: forms, backbone.js, backbone-forms

This is a silly question but I'm just getting started with Backbone and am a little stumped, is there an argument to pass in the schema to define a class for a form element? 
Example:

```
text_element_name:
  type: 'TextArray'
  class: 'myklass'
```

Output would be:

```
<textarea name="text_element_name" class="myklass"></textarea>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just found the "editorClass" that @Rayweb_on mentioned. Thanks!
Also found you can do:
`fieldAttrs: { class: "myklass", style: "display:none;" }`
which sets the classes on the parent element or containing div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about backbone.forms
then I think i will be something like this.

```
text_element_name : {
    type: 'TextArea',
    editorClass : 'myCssClass'

}
```